# What is the best way to create an populate complex objects with data from api?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a simple todo app. I have a server running on flask that returns a page when main route is accessed and has different endpoints like add_task, delete_task etc. and I access these endpoint via fetch() function and return an updated list of task from them in JSON.

My question is - What is the best way to create and populate a task list structure with following example markdown (below) with received info?

Markdown example:

```
<div class="task-list-container">
    <div class="task-container">
        <div class="task-header">
            <span>completion progress...</span>
            <span>created at ...</span>
            <span>due date...</span>
        </div>
        <div class="task-description">
            description...
        </div>
        <div class='task-comments'>task comments...</div>
        <div class='task-tags'>tags...</div>
    </div>
    ...another task
</div>
```

Returned JSON structure:

```
[
    {
        "task-id": int,
        "completion": bool,
        "created": date,
        "due date": date,
        "description": str,
        "comments": [str],
        "tags": [str]
    },
    {another task}
]
```

I could easily do it with React by creating component for it and simply populate a list of them by mapping through returned data but is there a way to do it neatly with vanilla JS?

Comment: You can create a web component that defines the markup of the task list. The component can be passed the data or its source and it should be able to fetch and display the result as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do it. One is to use a template literal to inject the variable task fields. For the asynchronous part (reading from the API), you would use `async` and `await`.

Here is how it could work for a dummy JSON provider:

```js
function renderTask(task) {
    return `<div class="task-container">
        <div class="task-header">
            <div>Task id: ${task.id}</div>
            <div>Task is ${task.completed ? "completed" : "in progress"}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="task-description">
            ${task.title}
        </div>
    </div>`;
}

async function refresh() {
    let response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/");
    let arr = await response.json();
    let html = arr.map(renderTask).join("\n");
    document.querySelector(".task-list-container").innerHTML = html;
}

refresh();
```

```css
.task-container { border: 1px solid; margin-top: 5px }
.task-header { font-weight: bold }
```

```html
<div class="task-list-container">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the tasks and for each task create the elements to the DOM,
Something like the below:

```
Object.keys(data).forEach((item, i) => {     
       let taskItem = document.createElement('div');
       let taskItemHeader = document.createElement('div');
       let taskItemDescription = document.createElement('div');
        ....
       taskItemDescription.innerHTML = item.description;
       taskItemHeader.appendChild(taskItemDescription);
       taskItem.appendChild(taskItemHeader);
       ....
     });
```